# Convert string to long integer when using CompareTo

Tags: java

I have this column of ID data but it's imported as string format :

```
020514705
020514707
020514711
020514715
020514718
```

To do  a sorting operation I am working with the compareTo function. 
So I need to convert them to long integer before calling the function :

This is the part of my code :

```
public class Personne implements Comparable {

    private String IDT_ETT_PSE;

    public Personne(String IDT_ETT_PSE) {
        this.IDT_ETT_PSE = IDT_ETT_PSE;
    }

    public String getIDT_ETT_PSE() {
        return this.IDT_ETT_PSE;
    }

     public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Personne other = (Personne) o;

           long x = Long.parseLong(this.IDT_ETT_PSE);

           long ConvertedInteger = Long.parseLong(other.getIDT_ETT_PSE());

            res = x.compareTo(ConvertedInteger);
return res;
}
```

My problem is in the line :

```
        res = x.compareTo(ConvertedInteger);
```

> Cannot invoke compareTo(long) on the primitive type long

How can I resolve it please ?

Comment: Use `Long.compare(x,ConvertedInteger)` instead

Comment: You can either compare two primitives with compareTo(long x, long y) or you can compareTo(Long anotherLong). In your case you could do compareTo(new Long(ConvertedInteger))

Comment: The problem with converting to long is that your identifiers seem to begin with a zero. In some cases, like telephone numbers, the initial zero is significant - `02` is *not* the same as `2` or `002`. Why aren't you comparing them as strings?